# How to convert a spark DataFrame with a Decimal to a Dataset with a BigDecimal of the same precision?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

How can I create a spark Dataset with a BigDecimal at a given precision? See the following example in the spark shell. You will see I can create a DataFrame with my desired BigDecimal precision, but cannot then convert it to a Dataset.

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
scala> case class BD(dec: BigDecimal)
scala> val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("dec", DecimalType(38, 0))))
scala> val highPrecisionDf = spark.createDataFrame(List(Seq(BigDecimal("12345678901122334455667788990011122233"))).map(a => Row.fromSeq(a)).asJava, schema)
highPrecisionDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dec: decimal(38,0)]
scala> highPrecisionDf.as[BD]
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot up cast `dec` from decimal(38,0) to decimal(38,18) as it may truncate
The type path of the target object is:
- field (class: "scala.math.BigDecimal", name: "dec")
- root class: "BD"
You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object;
```

Similarly I am unable to create a Dataset from a case class where I've used a higher precision BigDecimal.

```
scala> List(BD(BigDecimal("12345678901122334455667788990011122233"))).toDS.show()
+----+
| dec|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

Is there any way to create a Dataset containing a BigDecimal field with precision different to the default decimal(38,18)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default spark will infer the schema of the Decimal type (or BigDecimal) in a case class to be DecimalType(38, 18) (see `org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.SYSTEM_DEFAULT`)

The workaround is to convert the dataset to dataframe as below

```
case class TestClass(id: String, money: BigDecimal)

val testDs = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  TestClass("1", BigDecimal("22.50")),
  TestClass("2", BigDecimal("500.66"))
))

testDs.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- money: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

## Workaround

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
val testDf = testDs.toDF()

testDf
  .withColumn("money", testDf("money").cast(DecimalType(10,2)))
  .printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- money: decimal(10,2) (nullable = true)
```

You can check this link for finer details https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18484)

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like it is simply not possible right now to have a Dataset with specific precision BigDecimal. Unfortunately we have such BigDecimals in most of our DataFrames across our codebase. Using DataFrames everywhere means we lose out a lot on type safety and readability in terms of the reader knowing what columns are present in DataFrames at different points:(

Comment: Looks like it. Dataframes would provide you similar type safety as Dataset but if you think Dataset is they way to go then please raise a feature request and let's see what the reaction is. If this answer was helpful please do accept the answer.

Comment: DataFrames don't provide type safety as the compiler knows nothing about the names or types of the columns, so can't validate that. The other half of that problem is they don't provide that information to the reader either. e.g. If you read a table to a Dataframe in some code there is no way (without manually checking table) to know what columns you have. I will wait for a day to see if someone has a solution for Datasets with custom precision BigDecimals. If no other answers I will accept this one as the answer.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. I was thinking of something else from a type safety perspective

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is to use a String in the Dataset instead to maintain precision. This solution works providing you don't need to use the values as numbers (e.g. ordering or maths). If you need to do that you can turn it back into a DataFrame, cast to the appropriate high accuracy type, and convert back to your Dataset afterwards.

```
val highPrecisionDf = spark.createDataFrame(List(Seq(BigDecimal("12345678901122334455667788990011122233"))).map(a => Row.fromSeq(a)).asJava, schema)
case class StringDecimal(dec: String)
highPrecisionDf.as[StringDecimal]
```